# How to create Wordpress theme like

Tags: wordpress

How to create WordPress theme like this websites
one for govt jobs and another for show images slide

[www.indiangovtjobs.in](http://www.indiangovtjobs.in)

[www.imgcluster.com](http://www.imgcluster.com)

Answer (score 1):

the job website have use this theme:

```
Theme Name: News Pro Theme
Theme URI: http://my.studiopress.com/themes/news/
Description: A mobile responsive and HTML5 theme built for the Genesis Framework.
Author: StudioPress
Author URI: http://www.studiopress.com/
Version: 3.0.2
```

But this are not start, you can by on envato. Honestly i prefer use _S. It's a empty starter theme you can do what you want with this theme.